# Add class to Button_to in Active Admin

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, erb

In Rails 4, I'm trying to add a CSS class to a button, inside a loop, on Active Admin Dashboard like
    `button_to "Block", action: :block_cars, controller: :companies, id: company`

This however doesn't seem to work:

```
button_to "Block", :class => 'dangerbtn', action: :block_cars, controller: :companies, id: company
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` is an HTML option but you have it in the options hash.  Try like this instead:

```
button_to "Block", {action: :block_cars, controller: :companies, id: company}, {:class => 'dangerbtn'}
```

`button_to` has the format:

```
button_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
```

See [the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) for more details.